# Swift: How to use button to secondViewController by swift code

Tags: xcode, swift2

I have two UIViewController which are FirstViewControllet and SecondViewController. I am using "show" auction from firstViewControllerto connect the two UIViewController.

I have a problem, I don't know how to the secondViewController by swift code, can help me to fix this? Thank you

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserInput: UITextField!

@IBAction func btnSecondView(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (txtUserInput != 0) {
         print(User Input > 0)
         //go to SecondViewController
    } else {
         print(User Input < 0)
         //display alert message
    }
}
```

---

On the storyboard, I should make the Picture2 and Picture3?

Picture2:
[image]

1. make the connection.

Picture3:

[image]

2. Select the show of Manual Segue

---

I'm got the error Picture4.
How can I fix this, Thanks

Picture4:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let SecondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
self.presentViewController(SecondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

make sure you add 'SecondViewController' to the Identifier tab on your view controller in the Storyboard.

Comment: If you are using Storyboard, then yes.

Comment: Copy to Swift file of First OR second ViewContoller?

Comment: copy to where ever you have the `// go to SecondViewController` and make sure that in your Storyboard, you type in SecondViewController in the Identifier tab

Comment: if my SecondViewController name is MainMenuPageViewController. the code will be '
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                        
                        let MainMenuPageViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuPageViewController") as! MainMenuPageViewController
                        self.presentViewController(MainMenuPageViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
'

Comment: Hello, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, but like I said, you need to change the identifier, not just the name.

Comment: Can you give me the picture for the example

Comment: In storyboard. Click on your second view controller. Then, in the right pane, click on the third tab (the one that looks like an ID card) then click on storyboard ID, then type in mainmenu pageviewcontroller